# A set such that $A$, $A+A$ have density zero but $A+A+A$ has positive density.

Tags: additive-combinatorics, sumset

I have been thinking about Lagrange's theorem in terms of sumsets.  Certainly the perfect squares $\square = \{ n^2: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{ 0,1,4,9,\dots\}$ has density $0$.  In fact, I think 
$$ \square + \square = \{ a^2 + b^2 : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
also has density zero, but by Lagrange's 3 squares theorem $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ if $n \not \equiv 4^a(8k+7)$.  So that density is:
$$ d(\square+\square+\square) = 1 - \frac{1}{8}\big[ 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \dots  \big] > 0$$
How did this happen?  I just added finitely many sets of density $0$ and got a set with positive density.  Is this a contradiction?

Comment: Finally $d(\square + \square + \square + \square) = 1$ as all positive integers can be expressed as the sum of 4 squares.  So what is happening here?

Comment: There is no contradiction at all.

Answer (score 2):

Density zero has a wide range of refinements. The number of squares up to some large positive $N$ is about $\sqrt N.$ The number of sums of two squares is not much lower than $\sqrt N \cdot \sqrt N = N;$ two effects reduce that, some pairs sum to between $n$ and $2N,$ and there are some repeats such as $64+1 = 49+16.$ The count of distinct sums of two squares up to $N$ is actually about $0.7642 N / \sqrt {\log N}.$ This is asymptotically larger than the count of primes, for example.

By the time you get to four squares, you can't have more than $N$ distinct numbers represented up to $N.$ Some overage is due to represented numbers from $N$ to $4N,$ but most of it is due to considerable repetition, numbers represented many different ways.

Comment: Is that called log density? Not even. Like $\sqrt{\log}$ density.

Comment: @cactus314 probably the best book on counting arguments is Vaughan, The Hardy-Littlewood Method. http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511470929  I'm in the second edition